# creating a new pandas dataframe based on groups

Tags: python, pandas

The csv (sample below) shows the absolute error for an item for a given week (week_end_date). As the csv shows, an item belongs to a department, and a department has multiple items:
[image]

What I want to do is to create a new dataframe which has the following fields:

```
mdse_dept_ref_i     week_end_date      average_ABSError      num_items_in_department
```

Here is what I am able to do:

```
new_df = df.loc[df['mdse_dept_ref_i'] == 47]
num_items = new_df.groupby('week_end_date').size()

avg_abs_error = new_df.groupby(['week_end_date'])['ABSError'].mean()
new_df = num_items.to_frame().join(avg_abs_error.to_frame())
```

But, I don't know how to do this automatically for all the departments to create a single dataframe, because eventually I want to see how the number of items in a department is affecting the average error, and also be able to see the worst performing departments. Also, when I do a `groupby('week_end_date')`, the `week_end_date` becomes an index, whereas I would like it to be a field in the new dataframe, so that I can use it while plotting. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What does "some plotting" mean, exactly?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you give some examples as to the data format you want?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: please see the updated question

Comment: @Jacobm00: I want a new pandas dataframe with the fields shown in the question.

Comment: can you post the data rather than the image?

Comment: I have retracted my close vote. This is now a legitimately answerable question. You should avoid posting screenshots as much as you can though.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' groupby allows you to group by more than one field:

```
g = df.groupby(['mdse_dept_ref_i','week_end_date'])
num_items = g.size().to_frame('num_items')
avg_abs_error = g['ABSError'].mean()
df0 = pd.concat((num_items,avg_abs_error), axis = 1).reset_index()
df.merge(df0)
```

You can actually pass the argument `as_index = False` to the `.groupby`, but this has no effect when using `.size()`, so we have to reset the index later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), then `rename` columns and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `df`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['mdse_dept_ref_i','week_end_date'])['ABSError'].agg(['size','mean'])
d = {'size':'total', 'mean':'ABSError mean'}
df1 = df1.rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
                               total  ABSError mean
mdse_dept_ref_i week_end_date                      
47              3/25/17            3      39.988728
80              3/25/17            1       1.791748
204             3/25/17            1   12975.863000

df = df.join(df1, on=['mdse_dept_ref_i','week_end_date'])
print (df)
   mdse_item_i  mdse_clas_i  mdse_dept_ref_i  actual_sls week_end_date  \
0     19084539           30               47           0       3/25/17   
1     19517957           43               47           3       3/25/17   
2     19378250            0              204        1644       3/25/17   
3     19704764           43               47           0       3/25/17   
4     19119951            8               80          17       3/25/17   

   rnn_fcst_sls forecast_release_date      ABSError  total  ABSError mean  
0     48.520298               3/31/17     48.520298      3      39.988728  
1     44.795605               3/31/17     41.795605      3      39.988728  
2  14619.863000               3/31/17  12975.863000      1   12975.863000  
3     29.650280               3/31/17     29.650280      3      39.988728  
4     18.791748               3/31/17      1.791748      1       1.791748
```